# how to change the value in a cell in google spreadsheet when date changes

Tags: google-sheets

I want to create a prayer timetable in Google Spreadsheets.

There will be two different spreadsheets. One should display the whole month and the other should display daily information. I want the daily timetable sheet to pull data from the monthly spreadsheet whenever the date changes.

Can somebody tell me how to accomplish this?

Comment: Can you share a docs with us?

Answer (score 1):

With the data source sheet (on the right) called Sheet2 and having ColumnsA:B occupied as shown then in B2 of the sheet on the left:

```
=VLOOKUP(DAY(NOW()),Sheet2!A:B,2,0)
```

[image: SO13459251 example]

should achieve your requirement. It happened I also used a formula for the day of the month in ColumnA (`=DAY(NOW())`) but the value of A2 in Sheet1 does not affect the formula in B2, which should update automatically according to your computer’s clock though might not do so immediately unless you force a save.